# C# Kafka Producer using AWS MSK

Tags: c#, .net, apache-kafka, amazon-iam, aws-msk

I am currently trying to implement a C# dotnet Kafka producer which connects to my AWS MSK brokers.

The template code I am using is, with utilizes the Confluent.Kafka library:

```
 var producerConfig = new ProducerConfig
            {
                SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocol.SaslSsl,
                ClientId = "table-producer",
                BootstrapServers = "broker-1.host:port,broker-2.host:port,broker-3.host:port"
            };

            using (var producer = new ProducerBuilder<Null, dynamic[]>(producerConfig).Build())
            {
            }
```

I can't seem to find any documentation on how to authenticate against AWS MSK using IAM. Does the dotnet Confluent.Kafka library even support this?

Comment: Have you tried searching through the Confluent repo github issues? Someone has probably asked this before

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this? I am having same issue.

Comment: I took a look around the Confluent repo and found an unresolved feature request regarding this for their C/C++ library.
It is possible that dotnet version may also not be supported currently for IAM SASL as per the comment thread:
https://github.com/confluentinc/librdkafka/issues/3402